Beam Support Screen Porch
I have a 17’ screen porch span. I measured the beam across the top (6”w x 12”h) (not sure material, appears solid). Currently there is a center column support. I want to remove the center column to open the view space of the porch. The span holds the porch roof. Can I install arch corner supports? If so, what size? The porch (metal) roof load should be light, porch depth is 12’. The corner supports are 6” x 6”. Any suggestions and thanks.

Snow loads if any?  The beam material is very important.  Steel beam might okay, but wood not okay.  This is really a question for a local structural engineer if safe or not.  A centre support is usually added if the beam is not strong enough for the open span.  Removing snow all night in -20F weather is not fun.
